# Does the Invisibility Badge make me appear invisible to online players?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

If I equip the [Invisibility Badge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgnO96Csdik) then play a level in online multiplayer, will my character be invisible on other players' screens?

Comment: If this works like the random online multiplayer, you can see their silhouette if they have a wall on their background, otherwise they are completely invisible.

Comment: @pinckerman The random online multiplayer is what I was asking about.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, but my answer is still valid then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, other players with the Invisibility Badge will appear invisible to you during online multiplayer and vice versa. Players will become temporarily visible when using an emote.

Source: In RTGame's playthrough of Super Mario Bros. Wonder, at 59:49 he plays the Invisibility Badge challenge in online multiplayer.